# how to process submit on django-tables2 with a class View with FilterView mixin

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a django-tables2 FilterView.
The filter is templated in a form:

```
{% if filter %}
    <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
        {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
        {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

I have added a checkbox field to each row, and I have the table in a form:

```
<form action="table_selection" method="get" class="form form-inline">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_table table 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html' %}

    <button class="btn btn-primary red" type="submit" >Submit Rows</button>
</form>
```

When I submit, I get logging messages like:

```
GET /three_pl/threepl_fulfilments_filter/table_selection?csrfmiddlewaretoken=...
&select_row=198&select_row=158&select_row=159
```

so the select_rows are very interesting. 
But I am lost with the class view, I can't grapple with how to process the form submission.

This is my view:

```
class FilteredThreePLFulfimentsView(SingleTableMixin,FilterView):
    table_class = ThreePL_order_fulfilmentsTable
    model = ThreePL_order_fulfilments
    template_name = "three_pl/ThreePLFulfilmentsFilter.html"  #three_pl/templates/three_pl/ThreePLFulfilmentsFilter.html
    filterset_class = ThreePLFulfilmentsFilter
```

Comment: ah, I just noticed the URL of the submission with /table_selection

Answer (score 0):

Answer: set up a url watching for /table_selection.
Make it before the url for the table render.

```
...    url(r'^threepl_fulfilments_filter/table_selection',views.three_pl_fulfilments_selection,name='threepl_fulfilments_selection'),
...
```

and in the view:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    try:
        selected_rows = request.GET.getlist('select_row')
```